# Runtime.getRuntime().exec JAVA method not working with tshark -o

Tags: process, runtime, tshark

I am trying to capture packets using tshark from JAVA.[Pls find below]

If i tried the command from terminal (Ubuntu) its working. But from JAVA its throwing error tshark:

> Invalid -o flag "column.format:""source","

I tried following alternatives [error msg same]

```
String[] cmdArray = {"tshark -i any -o column.format:\"source, %s, srcport, %uS\" -f \"port 80 or port 443\""};
```

AND this:

```
String[] cmdArray = {"tshark -i any -o column.format:'source, %s, srcport, %uS' -f 'port 80 or port 443'"};


//CommandExc.java

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;


public class CommandExc
{
public static void main (String args[])
 {

    //This worked Succcessfully
    //String[] cmdArray = {"tshark -D","sudo tshark -D"};

String[] cmdArray = {"tshark -i any -o column.format:\"\"source\", \"%s\",\"srcport\", \"%uS\"\" -f \"port 80 or port 443\""};

    for (String cmd: cmdArray) 
    {
         System.out.println("Executing command : "+cmd);
        try
        {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); 
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            String str = in.readLine();
            while(str != null)
            {
                System.out.println(str);
                //  res += str + "\n";
                str = in.readLine();
            }
            in.close();          

            BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
            String str1 = in2.readLine();
            while(str1 != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Inside getErrorStream "+str1);
                //  res += str + "\n";
                str1 = in2.readLine();
            }
            in2.close();

            proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exit value is : "+proc.exitValue());
            proc.destroy();
        }
        catch(IOException | InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception on CommandExc class :" + e.toString());
                            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } //end of for
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked. refer http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/17881/issue-with-tshark-o

The problem why Java application reports an invalid -o flag is because the version of the Runtime.exec method is responsible for splitting the supplied string into separate command line arguments. By default, this method uses the space, tab, newline, carriage-return and the form-feed characters. So as you can see, because there is a white space character between [column.format:\"\"source\",] [\"%s\",], this version of the exec method treats them as 2 distinct arguments.

The solution will be to use the other version of the Runtime.exec method which takes the system command and arguments in as an array parameter. You can therefore manually split out the command line arguments and define them as separate strings in the array parameter as follows:

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "tshark", "-i", "any", "-o", "column.format:\"source\", \"%s\", \"srcport\", \"%uS\"", "-f", "port 80 or port 443"});